# Serving user images from Google Cloud Storage in Vue

Tags: vue.js, authentication, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, google-cloud-storage

Here is some background info for my project:

- A Django backend API with Django Rest Framework to communicate with the frontend
- A VueJS frontend (SPA) with Vuetify
- User authenticates with username and password and I use JWT to authenticate api requests (python lib is `djangorestframework-simplejwt`)
- I plan to host both frontend and API on the same Google App Engine
- The app has a photo gallery. User can only see its own photos.

Now I am not sure how to serve the photos... I guess Google Cloud Storage is the way to go.

Option 1
Initially I thought it would be simpler to retrieve the photos with the backend as it can simply authenticate to Cloud Storage with a service account. But I guess passing photos from backend to frontend through a serializer will be very slow. There can be a few hundred photos.

Option 2
It is probably far more efficient to only send the urls to the frontend (only the urls of current user). The frontend then gets images (e.g. `<v-img :src={{ photo.url }}>`). The problem is the client needs to authenticate to Google to be able to have read access to Cloud Storage. At this point I am lost.

- Should I use signed url?
- Should I authenticate the client to Storage with OAuth 2.0 as described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/javascript-implicit-flow). But as I understand it, it means user has to have a Google account and consent to terms, etc.
- Can I have object-level permissions or is it necessarily bucket-level?

Thanks for any insight you may provide!

Comment: Arg... Just realized I missed this section https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2#serviceaccount of the docs. Would that be the way to go for my use case?

Comment: Actually, there is a library `django-storages` for handling remote media and it has integration with google cloud storage. so take a look at the [docs](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading your use case I would recomend using Signed URLs.

According to the official documentation :

```
A signed URL is a URL that provides limited permission and time to make a request.
Signed URLs contain authentication information in their query string, allowing users without credentials to perform specific actions on a resource
```

[Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls)